# related classes of related classes django 1.9

Tags: python, django

I am building a site that display guides. 
Each guide has steps.
Each step has sub_steps.

I have done it with PK like this code.

How do I return for example sub_step 3 of step 5 in guide 2?

Also I have tried to do the inline admin function to add steps inside the guide and sub_steps inside the steps to keep it organised but can only get it to work with step in guide. How is this done?

```
class Guide(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    guide_category = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    guide_why = models.TextField()
    guide_how = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Step(models.Model):
    guide = models.ForeignKey(Guide, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sequence_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    step_title = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("guide", "sequence_number")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.step_title

class Task(models.Model):
    step = models.ForeignKey(Step, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sequence_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    task_title = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    task_img = models.ImageField()
    task_task = models.TextField()
    task_description = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("step", "sequence_number")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.task_title
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding of your first question: if you want to retrieve the steps and substeps by its sequence number, you cannot rely on the PK of each model, since the PK does not follow a sequence related to the parent table.

try this:

```
class Step(models.Model):
    guide = models.ForeignKey(Guide, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sequence_number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    step_title = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("guide", "sequence_number")


class Sub_step(models.Model):
    step = models.ForeignKey(Step, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sequence_number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    sub_step_title = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    sub_step_img = models.ImageField()
    sub_step_task = models.TextField()
    sub_step_description = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("step", "sequence_number")
```

`unique_together` will create a constraint in the database to ensure that there is a unique `sequence_number` for every parent object.

You need to set the `sequence_number` when the models are inserted in the database.

Then, you can do something like:

```
guide = Guide.objects.get(...)  # fetch by PK maybe
step_5 = Step.objects.get(guide=guide, sequence_number=5)
example = Sub_step.objects.get(step=step_5, sequence_number=3)
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT >>**

You need to consider these points:

- You can't set `default=1` to the sequence number; it must be unique for every parent model. You will need to manually update the sequence number or create a migration for that.
- As pointed by @Selecsosi, the `unique_together` constraints won't be applied. The names must refer to properties within the model.
- If you are managing your database through `migrations` (which you should), you may need to do this change in more than one step:

  1. add the `sequence_number` to the models, set the `null=True` property. Don't set the `unique_together` property in the `Meta` class.
  2. make and apply the migration
  3. create a migration to update the `sequence_number` of each model accordingly (check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) on how to create a custom migration).
  4. apply the migration, check that there are no duplicates on `parent_model, sequence_number` in the database
  5. set the `unique_together` property in the `Meta` class, remove the `null=True` property of the sequence numbers
  6. create and apply the migration
  7. take care of the `sequence_number` every time you insert new steps and substeps

**<< EDIT**

Comment: Thanks! I am trying it but I get errors when I try to migrate. 
`  return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: taskoftheday_step.guide_id, taskoftheday_step.sequence_number`

Comment: Well, that is easy. There is a duplicated step for a guide. How did you update the `taskoftheday_step.sequence_number` field?

Comment: I updated the code. Please take a look :) Is this good or do I need to change anything?

Comment: @9minday `sequence_number_step` in the Meta class and `sequence_number_task` aren't named the same so the constraint wont be applied in both `Task` and `Step`

Comment: @alfonso.kim I get another error now in the admin:

st Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/taskoftheday/guide/
Django Version: 1.9.4
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value: 
no such column: taskoftheday_guide.guide_title

Do i need to make changes in the admin.py?

`from .models import Guide, Step, Task

admin.site.register(Guide)
admin.site.register(Step)
admin.site.register(Task)`

Comment: that is because you have unapplied migrations, I guess.

Comment: @alfonso.kim I have run the make migrations and migrate successfully

Comment: in the admin, you are doing something like `guide.guide_title`. That property does not exist. You need to use `guide.name`

Comment: @alfonso.kim Thanks I changed name but now when i use migrate i get this error:

return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: taskoftheday_step.guide_id, taskoftheday_step.sequence_number